# prevent default behaviour using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have a anchor tag but I want to prevent the default behaviour using jquery. But not getting the exact solution. can you tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[name]").click(function(event){
     alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
     eventpreventDefault();
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a dot:

```
eventpreventDefault();
```

Should be:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

You can also use `return false` if you wish to disable default action (of going to specified link) as well as event bubbling:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[name]").click(function(event){
     alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
     return false;
   });
});
```