# Force Wordpress submenus to hide once you move your cursor away from them

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am on a mission to change the default behaviour of Top-Level menus in Wordpress.

For example, I have removed the link functionality from the top-level menus - because I only want people clicking on the sub-menus. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224160/prevent-top-level-menu-link-in-wordpress-admin-menu-from-working) if interested)

**What is my problem**

However, I am having an issue where if you click on one of the top-level items the browser 'focuses' on this and the sub-menu still stays active and out even when you move your cursor away. I want the submenu to disappear when you move your cursor - same as the behaviour when you haven't clicked on the top menu.

**What I have tried**

I have identified you can force this state by clicking on the link in inspect element and setting the state to focus.

I've tried writing some CSS to stop it happening, but didn't get anywhere with that.

I also added 'stopPropagation' to the jQuery for stopping the link, but it doesn't have the desired effect.

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            // Add the classes to target
            jQuery('a.toplevel_page_bnfo_portal, a.toplevel_page_bnfo_database, a.toplevel_page_bnfo_insights').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // cancel the event

                event.stopPropagation(); // Stops event propagating
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a solution using @sarfraz's suggestion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836869/prevent-default-behaviour-using-jquery) which targets 'on mouse down'

```
jQuery('a.toplevel_page_bnfo_portal, a.toplevel_page_bnfo_database, a.toplevel_page_bnfo_insights').on('mousedown', function(event) {
            // do your magic
                event.preventDefault();
});
```